# Implementing Cannons Algorithm in MPI

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm attempting to implement Cannons algorithm using MPI, I'm using this example code:

http://siber.cankaya.edu.tr/ozdogan/GraduateParallelComputing.old/ceng505/node133.html

There's a section that I'm not understanding. here's the example code.

```
37    /* Perform the initial matrix alignment. First for A and then for B */ 
38    MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 0, -mycoords[0], &shiftsource, &shiftdest); 
39    MPI_Sendrecv_replace(a, nlocal*nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, shiftdest, 
40        1, shiftsource, 1, comm_2d, &status); 
41 
42    MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 1, -mycoords[1], &shiftsource, &shiftdest); 
43    MPI_Sendrecv_replace(b, nlocal*nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, 
44        shiftdest, 1, shiftsource, 1, comm_2d, &status);
```

This is my current code.

```
MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size); 
MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank); 
MPI_Cart_coords(comm, rank, 2, coordinates); 

MPI_Cart_shift(comm, 0, -1, &rightrank, &leftrank);
MPI_Cart_shift(comm, 1, -1, &downrank, &uprank); 

MPI_Cart_shift(comm, 0, -coordinates[0], &shiftsource, &shiftdest); 
printf("coordinates[0] = %d for a shiftsource = %d, shiftdest = %d\n", coordinates[0], shiftsource, shiftdest);
//MPI_Sendrecv_replace(a, a->rowNum * a->colNum, MPI_INT, shiftdest, 
    //1, shiftsource, 1, comm, &status); 

MPI_Cart_shift(comm, 1, -coordinates[1], &shiftsource, &shiftdest); 
printf("coordinates[1] = %d for b shiftsource = %d, shiftdest = %d\n", coordinates[1], shiftsource, shiftdest);
//MPI_Sendrecv_replace(b, b->rowNum * b->colNum, MPI_INT, 
  //  shiftdest, 1, shiftsource, 1, comm, &status);
```

I call MPI_Cart_create in a different function, but it's the same basic call as in the example code.

```
MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);  /* get number of processes */
    .
    .
    .
if(is_perfect_square(size))  dim_size[0] = dim_size[1] = (int) sqrt(size);
else
{ //if size = 2 then dims = 2, 1; size = 4 then 2,2; 8 = 4, 2...
    dim_size[0] = (int) sqrt(size + size);
    dim_size[1] = dim_size[0] / 2;
}
MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 2, dim_size, periods, 1, &CannonsCart);
```

right now I'm just trying to understand what the point of shiftsource and shiftdest is. I'm assuming it's for the inital shift but when I run this code my printf statements say this.

```
coordinates[0] = 0 for a shiftsource = 0, shiftdest = 0
coordinates[1] = 0 for b shiftsource = 0, shiftdest = 0

coordinates[0] = 1 for a shiftsource = 1, shiftdest = 1
coordinates[1] = 1 for b shiftsource = 2, shiftdest = 2

coordinates[0] = 1 for a shiftsource = 0, shiftdest = 0
coordinates[1] = 0 for b shiftsource = 2, shiftdest = 2

coordinates[0] = 0 for a shiftsource = 1, shiftdest = 1
coordinates[1] = 1 for b shiftsource = 0, shiftdest = 0
```

I don't understand why the shiftsource and the shiftdest are the same. It should be one to the left and one up for matrix a and b.

the number of processes for this call (I.E. size) is 4 for this test case. If I need to I'll just host all of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument to `MPI_Cart_shift` is the displacement along the dimension (direction) specified by the second argument. For all processes that have coordinate `0` along the specified dimension, the displacement would be also `0` (because it is specified as `-coordinate[i]`), hence the source and the destination ranks would match the rank of the calling process.

You also get the same `shiftsource` and `shiftdest` when the displacement is `1` because your topology is 2x2 and you have periodic boundary conditions along both dimensions. The coordinate along the selected dimension of the previous rank would be `(coordinates[i] - 1 + 2) % 2` (here `(a - m + k) % k` computes `a - m` modulo `k`). But this is equal to `(coordinate[i] + 1) % 2`, which is exactly the coordinate of the next rank. Hence the coordinates of the previous and the next process conincide and therefore the ranks end up being the same.

Comment: I do currently have a 2 by 2 grid and it is periodic in both directions. I get how cart_shift calculates it's directions now, I still don't understand why Cannons algorithm has this section of code.

Comment: The algorithm uses circular shifts. After the last iteration the result is there, but it is unordered. One additional step is necessary in order to restore the initial distribution of the data so that it can later be gathered using the same communication pattern as the one used to scatter it.